# List Collection Names in MongoDB using Monk

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, monk

In my Node.js (Express) app that uses Monk, I need to render a list of all collections in the MongoDB database.

Is there a way to get the list of collections in the database using Monk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This wil basicaly do that, but it takes some digging into the underlying driver to do so:

```js
var db = require('monk')('localhost/test');

db.on("open",function() {
  console.log(
    db.driver._native.command(
      { "listCollections": 1 },
      function(err,result) {
        console.log( result.cursor.firstBatch.map(function(el) {
          return el.name;
        }))
    }
  )
);
```

});

The driver command is of course [**"listCollections"**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/listCollections/#dbcmd.listCollections) and those are the basic hoops you need to jump through to get there